# TERR error in calling API via jsonlite package

Tags: spotfire

I am using the following code to pull test data from an API, and I am getting the error shown below. Does anyone know what it means? (Note: key and identifier are input parameters in a text area).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
req2 <- httr::GET(paste("https://api.welldatalabs.com/jobsummaries/",identifier, sep=""), httr::add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", key)))
json2 <- httr::content(req2, as = "text")
jobSummaries <- fromJSON(json2)
jobSummaries.df <- as.data.frame(jobSummaries$rowData[[1]])
colnames(jobSummaries.df) <- jobSummaries$columnMetadata[[1]][[2]]
```

This is the error that I get;

> TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error: lexical
>   error: invalid char in json text.
>                                          d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.SPlusFunctionExecutor.d__0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionExecutorService.d__6.MoveNext()

Comment: I understand that there is HTML in what it is expecting to be JSON but I'm not sure what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the connection string to end in .json, and the error resolved itself.  Unfortunately, I now have an empty table with no columns, but that's a different problem.